# command \\ within HCode

Tags: htlatex

how can I use the command \\ within HCode? Within a javascript part which I embed with HCode, I need to use "\\alpha", however my htlatex always returns strange errors.
Best
Christian
Example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,german,twoside]{book}
\begin{document}
\HCode{<div id="box"  class="jxgbox" style="width: 650px; height: 530px;"></div>
<script>// \Hnewline
  board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5]});
  board.create('text',[-1,function(){return pal.Y()/2},"$\\alpha$"],{strokeColor:'black'}); }
</script> 
\end{document}
```

und aus dem cfg file

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>}
 \begin{document}
 \EndPreamble
```

Comment: could you please provide a minimal working example of your code? especially the JavaScript configuration.

Comment: sorry, since I need to use some html commands within the HCode, the code is not correctly displayed here. I hope, the most important line, that one with the JSXGraph command helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` character, for  example using `\string` command. First of all, I would move the code for board insertion out of the TeX file, because you wouldn't be able to compile it to PDF without error. I would create package `jsxgraph.sty`, which will contain some dummy command for the PDF mode:

```
\ProvidesPackage{jsxgraph}
\newcommand\jsxgraph{}

\endinput
```

The TeX file can be simplified to the following form:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,german,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{jsxgraph}
\begin{document}
\jsxgraph
\end{document}
```

The real work will be done in the configuration file for `tex4ht`, `jsxgraph.4ht`:

```
\renewcommand\jsxgraph{\a:jsxgraph}
\NewConfigure{jsxgraph}{1}
\Configure{jsxgraph}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div id="box"  class="jxgbox" style="width: 650px; height: 530px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">// \Hnewline
  board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5]});
  board.create('text',[-1,function(){return pal.Y()/2},"$\string\\alpha$"],{strokeColor:'black'}); 
</script>}}
```

The new configuration `jsxgraph` is defined here, with one parameter. The command `\jsxgraph` is redefined then, to include the configuration (using `\a:jsxgraph`). We can then use `\Configure{jsxgraph}{...}`. I changed two things to your original code: the `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` will prevent paragraph tags to be inserted around the graph, because it would result in invalid HTML code, and `\string\\alpha` will insert `\\alpha` string correctly.

This is the resulting HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">var a = "\\alpha";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script></head><body 
>
   <div id="box" class="jxgbox" style="width: 650px; height: 530px;"></div> <script type="text/javascript">//  
board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5]}); board.create('text',[-1,function(){return pal.Y()/2},"$\\alpha$"],{strokeColor:'black'}); </script> 
</body></html>
```